# Changing Integer Value inside an if and else statement

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to create some Java code in an if-and-else statement that goes between the two. When I run the code, the expected output should be: "hello world hello world" but all I get is "hello hello hello hello"

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong over here. Can somebody please tell me the problem?

```
int p = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    if (p == 1) {    
        System.out.println("hello");
        p = 2;
    } else {
        System.out.println("world");
        p = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what prints?

Comment: Check your curly braces

Comment: By the way, standard practice for indentation is that everything inside the `for` block should be indented to the right of the `for`.  Here, you have the first `if` starting in the same column as `for`, instead of indenting it.  If you had indented it, you probably would have spotted the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't all the code you have in your program, but look here:

```
    else
        System.out.println("world");
    p = 1;
}
```

Last curly brace doesn't belong to the `else` part of `if-else` statement, it belongs to the `for` loop that encloses an `if-else` part - improve formatting of your code and you will see the difference. Your `else` part isn't surrounded with curly braces, so only the first line after `else` word is executed when the second condition is to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

according to @ajb comment, you just move  `p = 1` to `else` block:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   if (p == 1) {
       System.out.print("hello");
       p = 2;
   } else {
      System.out.print("world\n");
      p = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a curly brace on the else block.

```
int p = 1;

for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
  if (p == 1){    
      System.out.println("hello");
      p = 2;
  }
  else {
      System.out.println("world");
      p = 1;
  }
}
```